# jquery ui datepicker is not working

Tags: jquery-ui

```
expected identifier is showing an error in side the function.
```

jquery ui datepicker  is not working in asp.net
i added these file in master page. but i used my class in aspx file.
    added scripts:

```
<script>
function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        changeMonth: true,//this option for allowing user to select month
        changeYear: true //this option for allowing user to select from year range
    });
}
</script>
code hear:
<td>Start Date:</td>
<td>                   
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" 
        SkinID="txtboxCustomizedMSkin" AutoPostBack="True" 
        OnTextChanged="txtStartDate_TextChanged" CssClass="datepicker">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgStartDate" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="Images/calender.png" CssClass="calender"/>
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="txtStartDate" PopupButtonID="imgStartDate" 
        Format="dd/MM/yyyy" CssClass="cal_Theme1" />
</td>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact error message. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!